# How websites find Facebook ID from URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hello a lot of websites propose to find your Facebook ID from a Facebook username.

By example :

findmyfbid.com
lookup-id.com

I thought the username is not anymore available as a field in facebook graph api now, so how these websitse find how to find the ID from an Url ?

W

Thanks

Raphael